# Having Issue on Using Glyphicons Icons in Bootstrap 3 Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/gpMEvZULTp) and let me know why the Glyphicons icons not centering (vertically) in the navbar?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-slide-dropdown">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-slide-dropdown">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>               
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>                
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" id="logIcon"></span></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The icon is outside the anchor. You should simply include it inside and everything should be fine

```
<li>
    <a href="#"> 
        Link 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" id="logIcon"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you used the `navbar-right` class use this code to show glyphicon before the Link name

```
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" id="logIcon"></span><a href="#">Link</a></li>
```